# Trying to get a local copy of my Linodes disk image but getting permission denied when logging in via SSH

Tags: ssh, backup, linode, user-permissions, disk-image

I'm following [this](http://library.linode.com/migration/ssh-copy#sph_preparing-the-receiving-computer) guide so I can download a copy of the disk image as I want to migrate to another host. When I get to the stage where this command needs to be entered:

```
ssh root@123.45.67.89 "dd if=/dev/xvda " | dd of=/home/archive/linode.img
```

(with the correct IP and a filepath of '/linode.img') I get a permission denied error, and I'm certain that I'm using the correct password as it works when normally logging in.

The strange thing is that it was working, but then after a disk image resize (I made it smaller as I was receiving an error saying there wasn't enough space when copying the image) it started giving me permission denied messages.

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that you're doing it wrong.

Here's what I'd do:

**Debian/Ubuntu**

On the old server

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections > package-selections
scp package-selections new-server:~/package-selections
```

On the new server

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < package-selections
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

**RedHat/Centos/ScientificLinux/etc.:**

```
rpm -qa > package-selections
```

and to restore

```
yum -y install $(cat package-selections)
```

That'll install the packages that were on the old server, on the new server.

Then the remaining thing to do is to use rsync to copy the contents of /home and /var/www over

I'd also copy over a copy of /etc/ but not push it into place automatically.  Instead, rsync it to /home/yourname/etc and cherry pick stuff out of it.

Alternatively, use [puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29).

Comment: Would this work for Drupal and Aegir installations?

Comment: That depends where they're installed into.  I'm trying to make the point that it's a bad idea to just blindly copy an entire image, I'd rather build a new server from the same packages that were used to create the first one.

Comment: Oh okay, I wasn't planning to restore directly from this image, rather just download it so I have a local copy of _everything_ before I close my account.

Comment: Oh.. In that case, why not just tar up /?

Comment: You can probably tell I'm quite new to all of this, I just did a quick search trying to find how to get a local copy of everything on my server and that guide came up. I'll look into doing that instead, thanks.